# Solve: $\dfrac{2}{x-6+\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{x}-2}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x}+3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation: $\dfrac{2}{x-6+\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{x}-2}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x}+3}$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{2}{x-6+\sqrt{x}}\cdot\dfrac{x-6-\sqrt{x}}{x-6-\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{x}-2}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+2}{\sqrt{x}+2}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x}+3}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-3}{\sqrt{x}-3}$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{2x-12-2\sqrt{x}}{(x-6)^2-x}+\dfrac{3\sqrt{x}+6}{x-4}=\dfrac{4\sqrt{x}-12}{x-9}$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{2x-12-2\sqrt{x}}{(x-4)(x-9)}+\dfrac{(3\sqrt{x}+6)(x-9)}{(x-4)(x-9)}=\dfrac{(4\sqrt{x}-12)(x-4)}{(x-4)(x-9)}$

$\Rightarrow 2x-12-2\sqrt{x}+3x\sqrt{x}-27\sqrt{x}+6x-54=4x\sqrt{x}-16\sqrt{x}-12x+48$

$\Rightarrow (3x-29)\sqrt{x}+8x-66=(4x-16)\sqrt{x}-12x+48$

$\Rightarrow 20x-114=(x+13)\sqrt{x}$

$\Rightarrow (20x-114)^2=(x+13)^2x$

$\Rightarrow 400x^2-4560x+12996=(x^2+26x+169)x$

$\Rightarrow 400x^2-4560x+12996=x^3+26x^2+169x$

$\Rightarrow x^3-374x^2+4729x-12996=0$

So far it looks computationally correct, but I can't be sure because the coefficients are abnormally large. But regardless I don't know how to solve for a third order equation (if my calculations aren't wrong). Or is there another way to compute this problem to avoid ending up with a third order equation? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Rationalizing the denominators is overkill, but you can still keep going with factorization using the rational root theorem. $12996=(2\times3\times19)^2$ and starting with the smaller divisors of $12996$ (i.e. $\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm6,\ldots$) will lead to $x+4$ as a factor of your cubic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> $\dfrac{2}{x-6+\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{x}-2}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x}+3}$

Let $t=\sqrt x$

$$\frac{2}{(t-2)(t+3)}=\frac{4}{t+3}-\frac{3}{t-2}$$

we get

$$2=4(t-2)-3(t+3)$$

so,

$$t=19$$
and

$$x=361$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\dfrac{2}{x-6+\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{x}-2}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x}+3} \\\iff \dfrac{2}{x-6+\sqrt{x}}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{x}+3}-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{x}-2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-17}{x-6+\sqrt{x}}$$

that is

$$2=\sqrt{x}-17 \iff\sqrt x =19 $$

which leads to $x=361$.